# Producer Consumer for Mobile Chat

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, actionscript, chat, producer-consumer

In Flex, created a Desktop and Web chat application using *producer and consumer method*.The code working fine in both. But when I tried the same code for mobile application I got the following error as follows,
"**sending failed**" "**Received fault**" "**Consumer subscribe error**" etc.

Is it possible to create a producer consumer chat application in mobile app?
Is there any other configuration needed for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I do not believe your question is answerable as is.  I strongly suggest you consider editing it to add some context to your question, and perhaps some code.  Conceptually, I see no reason you shouldn't be able to apply the Producer/Consumer design pattern to mobile development.

Comment: Did you succeed in creating the chat app for mobile? I have to make an IM chat function in my mobile app created in Flex/AIR and I really do not know where to start from. I would be happy if you could give me some tips.